# Is it possible to get out of order didUpdateLocations when using allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled

Tags: ios, gps, core-location, cllocationmanager, cllocation

I have added `[CLLocation allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled: timeout]` to my app.  Most of the time everything works fine.  Every now and then I get the current location when I turn on the screen in the middle of the deferred locations.  Is it possible that the location manager would send my app a `locationManager:didUpdateLocations:` for the current location and then call it with an array of deferred locations?  About the locations passed to `locationManager:didUpdateLocations` Apple's docs say

> This array always contains at least one object representing the
>   current location. If updates were deferred or if multiple locations
>   arrived before they could be delivered, the array may contain
>   additional entries. **The objects in the array are organized in the
>   order in which they occurred.** Therefore, the most recent location
>   update is at the end of the array.

I didn't see anything about the order in which `didUpdateLocations` is called.  Is there any guarantee that the delegate method didUpdateLocations is called in the correct order?

Thanks!

Stephen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I found the answer to this on developer.apple.com (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/251363?tstart=0).  Basically, yes this can happen.  When the device wakes up it first sends some individual locations for your current location and then sends the deferred locations.  This matches the behavior I see.  Here is the response from developer.apple.com.

> I was "sanitising" the time stamps so that my subsequent code would
>   not be confused by time going backwards.  I thought I had allowed for
>   this in deferred mode by sorting the batch of deferred locations by
>   time stamp on receipt, but actually I wasn't doing enough.  What
>   actually seems to happen when the device wakes after a deferred period
>   is that it sends a handful of individual locations first, with the
>   current time stamp, and then sends the large batch of saved GPS fixes.
>   So the lesson is that if you're going to try to sort your location
>   fixes you need to process more than just a single deferred batch.  You
>   really need to merge the new locations into your previously-received
>   locations, going back as far as necessary.   it's unfortunate that
>   deferred mode is so difficult to debug.